# Getting all users from db that participated for an activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently facing the following problem: Users are able to create activities. Other users have the possibility, to participate the activity. I now want that the users, which already participated to an activity are going to be listed in the view of the activity. So what I try is to show all the users that participated for an activity in the show method of the activity_controller with an activity_id.

The relations of the models are as follows:

```
 class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :participations
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participations
  has_many :reviews

end


 class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity
  has_many :activities
end




 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :participations
  has_many :reviews

end
```

My activity controller ist doing the following:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_activity, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

  def show
    @participated = Participation.where("activity_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @activity.id, current_user.id).present? if current_user
    @reviews = @activity.reviews
    @hasReview = @reviews.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) if current_user

    @participant = Participation.where (:activity_id == 'activity_id')
  end



  def new
    @activity = current_user.activities.build
  end

  def create
    @activity = current_user.activities.build(activity_params)

    if @activity.save

      redirect_to edit_activity_path(@activity), notice: "We want to give you a warm welcome!"

    else
      render :new, notice: "Something seems to be missing!"
    end
  end

  def edit
    if current_user.id == @activity.user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def update
    if @activity.update(activity_params)
      redirect_to edit_activity_path(@activity), notice: "Updated!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])

    if @activity.destroy
      redirect_to activities_path, notice: "Deleted!"
    end
  end

  private

  def set_activity
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  end


  def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:activity_name,
                                     :activity_starttime,
                                     :activity_duration,
                                     :activity_intensity,
                                     :activity_distance,
                                     :activity_topography,
                                     :activity_address,
                                     :activity_track,
                                     :activity_summary)

  end
end
```

Meanwhile the participations controller handles this:

```
    class ParticipationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def preload
    activity= Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    participations = activity.participations
    render json: participations
  end

  def create

    if Participation.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)

      redirect_to activities_path(@activity), notice: "Du nimmst bereits teil!"

    else

      @participation = current_user.participations.create(participation_params)
      redirect_to @participation.activity, notice: "Klasse, du nimmst nun teil!"

    end

  end


  def participant
    @participant = user.participations
  end

  def your_matches
    @matches = current_user.participations
  end

  def your_participations
    @activities = current_user.activities
  end

  private

  def participation_params
    params.permit(:activity_id, :status)
  end
end
```

In my view, I called the controller by using:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Wer kommt bis jetzt mit? </h3>


    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

      <% @participant.each do |participant| %>

          <tr>
            <td><%= participant.user.fullname %></td>
          </tr>

      <% end %>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me a list of all users that participated for any activity. But the only thing I want now is to show all the users which participated for the activity requested. I would say that my relations should work properly, therefore I guess I just need a small hint to solve the problem. At another point of my app I already got a list, where I am able to show the users which participated, but because of the different controllers, I am not able to call this from the activity controller. All in all, this causes an error because I am not able to call the participations_controller from an activitities_view.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
      <% activity.participations.each do |participation| %>


      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <%= link_to user_path(participation.user) do %>
              <%= participation.user.fullname %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
```

Would really appreciate any help and thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Some more information about what the DB include:

```
class CreateParticipations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :participations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :activity, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.string :status

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :activities do |t|

      t.string :activity_name
      t.datetime :activity_starttime
      t.time :activity_duration
      t.string :activity_intensity
      t.integer :activity_distance
      t.string :activity_topography
      t.string :activity_address
      t.string :activity_track
      t.string :activity_summary


      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `participation_params` hasn't the `user_id`?, just `activitiy` and `status`, but your migration has it.

Comment: It has. Via references he is fetching the user_id and activity_id. So a participations consists of the user_id, the activity_id and the status (which has no function so far, need to remove it...)

Comment: Can you provide a repository?

Comment: I got it, I'll take a look.

Comment: I'm assuming your are using your show route for activities to display these participants of a particular activity and your route is restful? If so pass along the activity id in the params hash, and plug it in to your instance variable query.  Something like this `@participant = Participation.where (activity_id: params[:id])`.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand when you add a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relantionship in your `Participation` model with reference to the `Activity` model.

If you'd have:

- User          `has_many` participations
- Activity      `has_many`
  participations
- Participation `belongs_to` user and `belongs_to` activity

Then you could join `User` with `Participation` in a query and try to get all the users that have participated to a particular activity like:

```
User.joins(:participations).where('participations.activity_id = 1')
```

Edit: I've tested your code, without touching nothing in the models, migrations, etc. I've inserted some example records like:

```
User.new(fullname: 'seb', ...).save
User.new(fullname: 'sab', ...).save
User.new(fullname: 'frank', ...).save

Activity.new(name: 'yoga', user_id: 1).save
Activity.new(name: 'pilates', user_id: 1).save
Activity.new(name: 'tennis', user_id: 2).save
Activity.new(name: 'etc etc etc', user_id: 3).save

Participation.new(user_id: 1, activity_id: 1).save
Participation.new(user_id: 2, activity_id: 1).save
Participation.new(user_id: 3, activity_id: 1).save
```

And I run the query, having 3 users that have participated in the activity with id 3:

```
User.joins(:participations).where('participations.activity_id = 1').pluck(:fullname)
```

And I get:

```
SELECT "users"."fullname" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "participations" ON "participations"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (participations.activity_id = 1)
# => ["seb", "sab", "frank"]
```

Comment: The relations are made as they are because: Every User is able to create an activity, but can also join an activity via participations. So I would say that the relations should work the way I want, or do I miss a thing? If I add your code to my controller's show method and call it from the activities/show.html.erb I still get all participants that participated to any activity, and not only the specific users that participated.

Comment: So, I was omitting that part, I meant the Participation `belongs_to :activity`
and `has_many :activities` part. Did that query gave you some error?

Comment: What about adding the user_id? `User.joins(:participations).where('participations.activity_id = 1 AND participations.user_id = 1')` for instance.

Comment: If I change the relations I am getting an error. The only line I can remove is `has_many :users, through: :participations` , which causes no change at all. Adding the ID also leads to an error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: participations.activity_i‌​d: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "participations" ON "participations"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (participations.activity_i‌​d = 1 AND participations.user_id = 1)`

Comment: I do not get why I am not able to make it like I posted right before my edit. In this case I first call the activities and afterwards the participations. In this case the participations_controller seems is also calling the information from the activities_controller and therefore, I do not understand why it is not working the opposite way...

Comment: So in that case, as you mentioned, you'd need to make two steps to get the result, through your relationships it should be easier.

Comment: Oh damn. I did not see your edit from yesterday...I just tried your last approach with pluck and this returns me the right sets of users which participated for the specific activity (in this case `activity` with `activity_id = 1`). Thank you so far, my approaches where not able to do this. I now have to only find a way to only get the data for the called activity from the database, so `activity_id = 1` needs to be dynamic in somehow.

Comment: Think I finally got it. Changing your approach to: `User.joins(:participations).where('participations.activity_id = ?', @activity.id).pluck(:fullname)` gives me the right set of users for the right activity. Hopefully this works! Thank you so much and thank you for taking some time! I think I need to rework this topic again for myself...